# Make text <span> sit below lightbox image

Tags: html, css

I have a gallery which has a number of images. They have a set width and no height to the image and the height is obviously just what the image is, so one could be 500px in height and the next one could be 620px in height.

Here is the css for this:

```
.mygallery { width: 650px; padding:0; margin:0; }
```

I have a caption which needs to go directly below the image and the css for this is:

```
#category span{color:#FFFFFF;}
```

Can anyone help me how I can put the category span below my gallery. I just cannot get it to go underneath. Obviously it would be fine if all the images were the same height, but as they are all different its proving difficult.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you do a jsfiddle? Or at least post your HTML.

Comment: Also - have you tried using a block-level element (Spans are inline, and this will try to sit next to elements). A DIV will automatically go on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

A natural structure for images in HTML would be something like this:

```
<figure>
  <img>
  <figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
```

The `figure` element could be made an `inline-block` (if you want to list more than one element on a line), and the rest would normally be displayed as `blocks`. This structure should make it possible to do what you want. The `span` has to go—or be told to display as a `block` element—it is part of the problem here.